# How to fetch data from table as per column value using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter value from table as per column value using PHP and MySQL. Here is my data:

db_images:

```
image_id     member_id      subcat_id   from_day   to_day

  1           220            56           1         3

  2           220            56           1         3

  3           220            56           1         1

  4           120            22           1         5

  5           120            22           2         4
```

Here is my query:

```
$qry=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from db_iamges group by member_id,subcat_id order by image_id desc");
```

Using my query I am getting a record like below:

```
image_id     member_id      subcat_id   from_day   to_day

    3           220             56         1          1
```

I need the `to_day` should always be higher value. If same `member_id and subcat_id` is present the the to_day will be always higher value and the from_day will be always smaller value. The expected output should like below.

```
image_id     member_id      subcat_id   from_day   to_day

   1            220             56          1        3

   4            120             22          1        5
```

Comment: Try adding `WHERE from_day < to_day`.

Comment: in case of my last record will it work ?

Comment: That will just insure that `from_day` is smaller than `to_day`.

Comment: But i need from_day will smallest no and to_day will highest no.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have syntax problems, because if you copy-paste, you put "db_iamges". I made a table:

```
mysql> select * from prueba1;
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| image_id | member_id | subcat_id | from_day | to_day |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
|        1 |       220 |        56 |        1 |      3 |
|        2 |       220 |        56 |        1 |      3 |
|        3 |       220 |        56 |        1 |      1 |
|        4 |       120 |        22 |        1 |      5 |
|        5 |       120 |        22 |        2 |      4 |
|        6 |       120 |        22 |        2 |      9 |
|        7 |       120 |        22 |        2 |      2 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And:

```
mysql> select image_id, member_id, subcat_id, min(from_day), max(to_day) from prueba1 group by member_id, subcat_id order by image_id asc;
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| image_id | member_id | subcat_id | from_day | max(to_day) |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
|        1 |       220 |        56 |        1 |           3 |
|        4 |       120 |        22 |        1 |           9 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It is working

EDIT: Updated, as I didn't understand your main problem.

Comment: As shown in Satya's output there is small change,  --- select image_id, member_id, subcat_id, min(from_day), max(to_day) from test2 group by member_id, subcat_id order by image_id asc;   Just you need to change order by image_id desc to asc.

Comment: I was using his example, but you're right, I'll change the answer. Thanks

Comment: Paste your full commands and tables, it is working on my end.

Comment: And please, use PDO

Comment: @MarioV :  here is my query `select sl.image_id,sl.member_id,sl.subcat_id,sl.date_from,sl.date_to,min(sl.from_day) as frmDay,max(sl.to_day) as toDay,sl.image,b.rest_name,b.member_id,s.subcat_name,s.subcat_id,d1.day_name as from_day_name,d1.day_id,d2.day_name as to_day_name,d2.day_id from db_special_images as sl left join db_subcategory as s on sl.subcat_id=s.subcat_id left join db_restaurant_basic as b on sl.member_id=b.member_id left join db_day as d1 on d1.day_id=frmDay left join db_day as d2 on d2.day_id=toDay  group by sl.member_id,sl.subcat_id order by sl.image_id desc`.

Comment: @MarioV : Actually i am joining many tables and i am getting error at this `left join db_day as d1 on d1.day_id=frmDay` line.

Comment: Please add the full query, and the full output error

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  T.*
From db_images t
Inner join (
  Select member_id, subcat_id, max(to_day) to_day
  db_images group by member_id,subcat_id
) t2 on t.member_id = t2.member_id
And t.Subcat_id = t2.subcat_id
And t.to_day = t2.to_day;
```

Answer (score 0):

use max(column name) to get higher value .

```
select image_id, member_id,subcat_id,from_day, max(to_day) as to_day from from db_iamges group by member_id,subcat_id order by image_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select t1.* from db_images t1 inner join(select max(member_id) as 
mid,max(subcat_id) as cid,min(from_day) as fdy from db_images group 
by member_id) t2 on t1.member_id = t2.mid and t2.cid = t1.subcat_id
and t2.fdy = t1.from_day group by member_id order by image_id asc;
```

[check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/249315/5)